# Python Import error Opencv NameError: name highgui is not defined

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew

Python 2.7.5

I added the homebrew/science to my brew taps.

I ran

```
brew install opencv.
```

bash profile I added

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I've opened the headgazer folder and run

```
python tracker.py


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tracker.py", line 21, in <module>
    from roi_detector import ViolaJonesRoi
  File "/Users/username/Downloads/headtracker_version_0.0/roi_detector.py", line 21, in <module>
    import opencv as cv
ImportError: No module named opencv
~/Downloads/headtracker_version_0.0:.
```

Ok, looks like it's called opencv2. So I swap out occurances of import opencv as cv with

```
import cv2 as cv
```

now in viola_jones_opencv.py I have

```
import cv2 as cv
from cv import *
from cv.highgui import *
```

And I get an error on importing highgui

```
ImportError: No module named highgui
```

Comment: what error  do you get when importing highgui?

Comment: Added, last paste didn't get it. No module named

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no highgui module in opencv's python api. (full-stop)

actually , all your import statements look dorky.

(renaming cv2 to cv is a bad idea, since there existed an old cv module before. you're only confusing yourself and others this way)

replace all of them with :

```
import cv2
```

and stick with :

```
cv2.imshow() 
cv2.waitKey()
```

etc

[EDIT]

if you're trying to run [something like this](https://github.com/opengazer/HeadTracker/blob/master/viola_jones_opencv.py) ,

then there's bad news for you. opencv comes with it's own python bindings since a very long time now, but apart from that, there exist several outdated 3rd party bindings. the code you're trying to run seems to be one of those, so you can't use it with opencv's builtin api.

Comment: I was doing the replace based on another SO post for a similar question. No highgui, huh. So it looks like I need to figure out what was moved out of highgui, or install opencv's own python? Damn, I just want software to track eye movements.

Comment: you either have to adapt the code to cv2 api or find out which darn python wrapper the original code was using.

Comment: blame those devs for living under a rock !

Comment: that does not sound fun. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there is no highgui module so I do not know what you ar doing. Also, I agree with berak as renaming anything imported is a pretty bad idea. You just sometimes dont know if there is another directory named the same thing. Good luck on your fix anyways.